# Failed to find certificate in publishsettings file in Sitecore azure

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-azure

I have installed sitecore azure and then creating an editing farm giving me below error

Failed to find certificate in publishsettings file. Sitecore.Azure.UI.Exceptions.SubscriptionIsNotInListException: SubscriptionId is not presented into publishsettings file at Sitecore.Azure.UI.Shell.Applications.Azure.AzureControls.Dialogs.PublishSettingsUploader.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

[image]

I opened the .publishsetting file in notepad and found that the subscription is is placed there.
I had downloaded the .publishsetting file from 
https://manage.windowsazure.com/PublishSettings/index?client=&schemaVersion=1.0

Answer (score 0):

I have disables the analytics and now it is resolved